# How to draw unfilled figures on Android?

Tags: android, drawing, fill

Is it possible to draw unfilled figures on Android? By default circles and rectangles are filled.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You need to change the `Paint` style to stroke if you just want an outline with no fill:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: Using green color when painting. After changing style to stroke I'm getting a black fill. Is it possible to get it to be transparent?

Comment: @arcone `p.setColor(0x99000000);` The color-parameter accepts an hex-code in the form 0xaarrggbb (a=alpha, r=red, g=green, b=blue)